# What is the proper way of editing com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist

Tags: macos, mac, system-preferences, text-to-speech, plist

I want to edit that file programmatically, to toggle between the Dutch Siri voice and the American Siri voice.

I tried doing the following in bash

```bsh
defaults write com.apple.speech.voice.prefs SelectedVoiceID 5190
defaults write com.apple.speech.voice.prefs SelectedVoiceName 'Pieter Siri'
```

But that only ended up corrupting the file and making the speech synthesis server unable to boot. After resetting the file (by deleting it and letting macOS generate a new one), I investigated what was going on.

My findings are as follows. There's a few other speech related plist files close to this one, when I open any of those in sublime I get something that suggests it's a binary file. Namely it looks like this:

[image: com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist in Sublime Text]

However, for some reason, `com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist` does not appear that way in Sublime Text.

[image: com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist in Sublime Text]

So I can imagine that, since it's stored in a different format, it may also need to be edited differently. Does anybody have any idea how to edit that file correctly?

Comment: Have you tried [plutil](https://osxdaily.com/2016/03/10/convert-plist-file-xml-binary-mac-os-x-plutil/) to convert the format?

Answer (score 0):

Get [X-code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) (8gb) or [Prefs Editor](http://apps.tempel.org/PrefsEditor/index.php) (free), IMO this is easier as you don't have to convert `plist` files.